# Indexing \int with amsmidx

Tags: math-mode, symbols, indexing

I've used `amsmidx` to create a separate notational index.

```
\usepackage{amsmidx}
\makeindex{idx}
\makeindex{nidx}
\newcommand{\idx}[1]{\index{idx}{#1}}
\newcommand{\nidx}[1]{\index{nidx}{#1}}
```

I need to index symbols like `$\int_{\mathcal{D}}$`, `$\int^{\underline{\mathcal{D}}}$` (resp an end, an enriched coend). But doing so breaks everything. If I type

```
\nidx{$\int^{\mathcal{C}}$}
```

and then run `makeindex nidx`, it will accept but then on the next pass I'm told there is a missing `$`. Indeed, when I look in the `nidx.ind` file I see

```
\item  ^{\mathcal  {C}}$, 6
```

I thought the issue might be that `makeindex` doesn't know how to alphabetize these entries but

```
\nidx{int@$\int^{\mathcal{C}}$}
```

causes `makeindex nidx` to reject the entry. (But then everything else compiles at least.)

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The `\index` macro tries hard not to expand its argument, but if you give it as an argument to another command this protection does not work any more; you should do

```
\newcommand{\idx}{\index{idx}}
\newcommand{\nidx}{\index{nidx}}
```

so that the call `\nidx{int@$\int$}` will be first transformed into

```
\index{nidx}{int@$\int$}
```

but *without* absorbing the main argument; now `\index` will apply correctly its protection mechanism.

The problem, of course, might present again in case `\nidx{int@$\int$}` is buried as argument to another command; in such cases, I hope rare, put `\protect\int` instead of `\int`.

What other commands need this protection if the index entry appear in the argument to a command? It's hard to make a list; surely `\mathcal` doesn't, but `\int` and `\underline` do. Just look at the produced `idx` files and it will be quite obvious which ones.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! That sorted me out. I didn't need to protect any of this but I'll remember for the future.